# Need to strip numbers out of a filename string to change save location

Tags: vba

I'm having an issue where I need to strip a filename from a path but can't quite figure out the code.

An example filename would be C:\Checked out parts\001-1099-01.slddrw. I need to extract the "001-1099-01." portion. The file location to the left could be anything and the only constants in the file name are the "001-" portion (which I should point out, could repeat if the filename was 001-1001-03) and the ".slddrw". Other than that the filename could be named "001-10999-03-02-01".

I have stripped out the slddrw portion easily, I tried using Right and InStr functions to strip the rest off but I think that InStr only works with letters (couldn't find any number examples anyways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Public Sub test()

Dim strFileName As String

'Your sample file name
strFileName = "C:\Checked out parts\001-1099-01.slddrw"

'Search for the first occurance of \ in the reversed (!) file name
'  if you substract this result from the length of the string
'  you know where to start (+ 2 to avoid the \ itself)
strFileName = Mid(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStr(1, StrReverse(strFileName), "\") + 2)

'Remove the .slddrw portion from the end
strFileName = Replace(strFileName, ".slddrw", "")

'Done
Debug.Print strFileName

End Sub
```

Note the comments in the code for more information.

Comment: Thanks! the first part worked great but the replace function wasnt working. I used 

    strFileName = Left(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - 6)

and that works fine.

Comment: Strange that `Replace` wouldn't work. But in that case I'd rather use `strFileName = Split(strFileName, ".")(0)` as noted in the solution provided by @Oligg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub in which you define the path and extension of your file and it will give you the filename.

```
Sub getFileName()
Dim myString() As String
Dim path As String, extension As String
Dim fileName As String

path = "C:\Checked out parts\"
extension = ".slddrw"
'Say your string is in cell A1
myString = Split(Range("A1"), path)
fileName = Split(myString(1), extension)(0)

MsgBox fileName 'fileName can be used elsewhere after
End Sub
```

You could also do it as a function:

```
Function getFileName(cel As Range, path As String, extension As String)
Dim myString() As String

myString = Split(cel, path)
getFileName = Split(myString(1), extension)(0)
End Function
```

If you have the path and extensions stored in cells, you can use this function:

```
Function getFileName2(cel As Range, path As Range, extension As Range)
Dim myString() As String

myString = Split(cel, path)
getFileName2 = Split(myString(1), extension)(0)
End Function
```

Those are the options I can think of, hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

If you don't know the path nor the extension, you can use this instead:

```
myString = Split(Range("A1"), "\")
fileName = Split(myString(UBound(myString)), ".")(0)
```

Comment: you can always split the string by \ and use the last portion since there will never be a \ in a filename or extension